# How to fire up the stock Gallery app with an image url that's in sd card

Tags: android, gallery, nullpointerexception, stock

I have an image on the sd card. I need to fire up the stock Gallery app from my app to show the image. I get a NullPointerException from the stock Gallery app.

Here is my code.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setType("image/png");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(IMAGE_URL_ON_SD_CARD));
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(i);
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/16")));
```

If above code do not work thn try like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*"); startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: These are all equivalent. As I was expecting - the same result. There is something - some setting - is not being provided or is being wrongly provided. 
I can see other apps push images to the stock Gallery, which works just fine. Any - better quality - help would be highly appreciated.